# How to configure squid document root?

Tags: webserver, squid

I looked up squid.conf, but I didn't find a tag to configure document root. Where is the default path? which tag is to configure.

Comment: This is a question for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what do you want to do, as far as I know squid doesn't use a "document root" that name sounds more like an Apache configuration. Can you give more details on what do you want to do with squid? Or what is the Document Root that you look for?

Comment: I want to put some html page into a place, and access them through squid. but I don't know where to put. for example: http://(squid server)/test.html. where should test.html be placed?

Comment: I belive you are mixing two things, apache and squid... you need apache installed in your_server so you can enter http://your_server/test.html (that path is from apache and is /var/www/) now if you want to give permission to your lan to access http://your_server/test.html via a squid server that's a different idea and have nothing to do with apache.